# PouchDB - stop live replication

Tags: pouchdb

After having setup a `continuous` (live) replication in PouchDB, how do I find these (like active tasks for `_replicate` or the `_replicator` in CouchDB)?

Or rather, how do I cancel them?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [pouchdb-persist](https://github.com/redgeoff/pouchdb-persist) and then you can do:

```
var db = new PouchDB('todos');
var persist = db.persist({ url: 'http://localhost:5984/todos' });
```

and then later:

```
persist.stop();
```

and then later:

```
persist.start();
```

Or, depending on your use case, you might be able to just use the default functionality of [pouchdb-persist](https://github.com/redgeoff/pouchdb-persist).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

var from = db.replicate.from (remoteDB, { live : true });

from.cancel();

Comment: thanks, yes, but if you don't have access to the result of the replication function? More like getting ongoing replications?

Comment: There's currently no way to do this. But since an analog exists in CouchDB, I think we'd be interested in implementing a `PouchDB.getActiveTasks()` or something.

Comment: Hi Nolan, does the cancel() actually stops the replication (and clears the tasks and allocated resources) or it only stops receiving replication notifications/changes? The reason for asking is that I need to start continuous replication and stop it when the device (it's a mobile app) goes online or offline respectively. These events happen every now and then and it seems that replication resources do not get released — it could also be a bug of my app, still investigating.

Comment: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication : 'This method returns an object with the method `cancel()`, which you call if you want to cancel live replication.'